# Mysql: how to generate count table by PATTERN / LIKE statement ? very tricky

Tags: mysql

to simplify, I got a database of registered users, I want to count how many emails there are for each email domain name (note I do not know all domain names)

for example,
Users table-

```
id    |    email
------------------
1     | test@hotmail.com
2     | test@somesite.aaa<--unknown to me
3     | test@unknownsite.aaa<--unknown to me
4     | test@hotmail.com
5     | test@somesite.aaa<--unknown to me
6     | test@yahoo.com
7     | test@yahoo.com
8     | test@hotmail.com
```

( note: I want to count each email without specifying which email exactly )

so the result I want is

```
suffix         |   count
hotmail.com    |    3
somesite.aaa   |    2
unknownsite.aaa|    1
yahoo.com      |    2
```

**again, I stress this, I do not know unknownsite.aaa nor can i mention it in a statement because it is unknown to me, i hope I am clear.**

So essentially I want to make a statistic of what my website users use as an email host website.
but like I said and I will repeat the third time, **I do not know every mailhost that exists.**

I am going to investigate this more, I have a feeling this is something mysql cannot handle.

EDIT:

I came up with the following solution, but seems tiny bit redundant, which I hate :P

```
select substring_index(`email`,'@',-1),count(*) as count from users group by substring_index(`email`,'@',-1) order by count ASC;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT   SUBSTRING_INDEX(email, '@', -1) AS suffix, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM     users
GROUP BY suffix
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7c14f/1/0).

Answer (score 0):

use RLIKE or REGEXP in mysql

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html

Comment: In this case a regexp is massive overkill, though.